# Neofetch: subtitle off battery adds random 1 before colon (separator), and how to (if possible) remove mount info from memory subtitle

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, desktop-environment, pop-os

Hi here is the output of neofetch:
[image]

as you can see the battery outputs
'1 > 99% [Discharging]'
My question is: How do i remove the 1 between  and >?
When i put a non icon i have the same problem:
[image]
Here is my (neofetch) config.conf (with 'Hello World' as battery)

```
# https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Customizing-Info
print_info() {
    info title        "┌─────────=title=─────────┐"
    info underline    "- - - - - - - - - "

    prin "┌──────────────=SOFTWARE=──────────────┐"

    info "" distro
    info "" kernel
    info "" packages
    info "" shell
    info "" term
    info "" gpu_driver  # Linux/macOS only
    info "Hello, world" battery
    info "" uptime

    prin "├──────────────=HARDWARE=──────────────┤"

    info "" cpu
    info "" gpu
    info "" disk
    info "" memory
    info "" resolution

    prin "└───────────────=COLORS=───────────────┘"

    info cols



    # info "DE" de
    # info "Terminal Font" term_font
    # info "WM" wm
    # info "WM Theme" wm_theme
    # info "Theme" theme
    # info "Icons" icons
    # info "Host" model

    # info "Font" font
    # info "Song" song
    # info "cpu usage" cpu_usage
    # [[ "$player" ]] && prin "Music Player" "$player"
    # info "Local IP" local_ip
    # info "Public IP" public_ip
    # info "Users" users
    # info "Locale" locale  # This only works on glibc systems.


}


# Kernel


# Shorten the output of the kernel function.
#
# Default:  'on'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --kernel_shorthand
# Supports: Everything except *BSDs (except PacBSD and PC-BSD)
#
# Example:
# on:  '4.8.9-1-ARCH'
# off: 'Linux 4.8.9-1-ARCH'
kernel_shorthand="on"


# Distro


# Shorten the output of the distro function
#
# Default:  'off'
# Values:   'on', 'tiny', 'off'
# Flag:     --distro_shorthand
# Supports: Everything except Windows and Haiku
distro_shorthand="off"

# Show/Hide OS Architecture.
# Show 'x86_64', 'x86' and etc in 'Distro:' output.
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --os_arch
#
# Example:
# on:  'Arch Linux x86_64'
# off: 'Arch Linux'
os_arch="on"


# Uptime


# Shorten the output of the uptime function
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'tiny', 'off'
# Flag:    --uptime_shorthand
#
# Example:
# on:   '2 days, 10 hours, 3 mins'
# tiny: '2d 10h 3m'
# off:  '2 days, 10 hours, 3 minutes'
uptime_shorthand="on"


# Memory


# Show memory pecentage in output.
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --memory_percent
#
# Example:
# on:   '1801MiB / 7881MiB (22%)'
# off:  '1801MiB / 7881MiB'
memory_percent="on"


# Packages


# Show/Hide Package Manager names.
#
# Default: 'tiny'
# Values:  'on', 'tiny' 'off'
# Flag:    --package_managers
#
# Example:
# on:   '998 (pacman), 8 (flatpak), 4 (snap)'
# tiny: '908 (pacman, flatpak, snap)'
# off:  '908'
package_managers="tiny"


# Shell


# Show the path to $SHELL
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --shell_path
#
# Example:
# on:  '/bin/bash'
# off: 'bash'
shell_path="off"

# Show $SHELL version
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --shell_version
#
# Example:
# on:  'bash 4.4.5'
# off: 'bash'
shell_version="on"


# CPU


# CPU speed type
#
# Default: 'bios_limit'
# Values: 'scaling_cur_freq', 'scaling_min_freq', 'scaling_max_freq', 'bios_limit'.
# Flag:    --speed_type
# Supports: Linux with 'cpufreq'
# NOTE: Any file in '/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq' can be used as a value.
speed_type="bios_limit"

# CPU speed shorthand
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values: 'on', 'off'.
# Flag:    --speed_shorthand
# NOTE: This flag is not supported in systems with CPU speed less than 1 GHz
#
# Example:
# on:    'i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz'
# off:   'i7-6500U (4) @ 3.100GHz'
speed_shorthand="off"

# Enable/Disable CPU brand in output.
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --cpu_brand
#
# Example:
# on:   'Intel i7-6500U'
# off:  'i7-6500U (4)'
cpu_brand="on"

# CPU Speed
# Hide/Show CPU speed.
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --cpu_speed
#
# Example:
# on:  'Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz'
# off: 'Intel i7-6500U (4)'
cpu_speed="off"

# CPU Cores
# Display CPU cores in output
#
# Default: 'logical'
# Values:  'logical', 'physical', 'off'
# Flag:    --cpu_cores
# Support: 'physical' doesn't work on BSD.
#
# Example:
# logical:  'Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz' (All virtual cores)
# physical: 'Intel i7-6500U (2) @ 3.1GHz' (All physical cores)
# off:      'Intel i7-6500U @ 3.1GHz'
cpu_cores="off"

# CPU Temperature
# Hide/Show CPU temperature.
# Note the temperature is added to the regular CPU function.
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'C', 'F', 'off'
# Flag:    --cpu_temp
# Supports: Linux, BSD
# NOTE: For FreeBSD and NetBSD-based systems, you'll need to enable
#       coretemp kernel module. This only supports newer Intel processors.
#
# Example:
# C:   'Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz [27.2°C]'
# F:   'Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz [82.0°F]'
# off: 'Intel i7-6500U (4) @ 3.1GHz'
cpu_temp="off"


# GPU


# Enable/Disable GPU Brand
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --gpu_brand
#
# Example:
# on:  'AMD HD 7950'
# off: 'HD 7950'
gpu_brand="off"

# Which GPU to display
#
# Default: 'all'
# Values:  'all', 'dedicated', 'integrated'
# Flag:    --gpu_type
# Supports: Linux
#
# Example:
# all:
#   GPU1: AMD HD 7950
#   GPU2: Intel Integrated Graphics
#
# dedicated:
#   GPU1: AMD HD 7950
#
# integrated:
#   GPU1: Intel Integrated Graphics
gpu_type="all"


# Resolution


# Display refresh rate next to each monitor
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --refresh_rate
# Supports: Doesn't work on Windows.
#
# Example:
# on:  '1920x1080 @ 60Hz'
# off: '1920x1080'
refresh_rate="off"


# Gtk Theme / Icons / Font


# Shorten output of GTK Theme / Icons / Font
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --gtk_shorthand
#
# Example:
# on:  'Numix, Adwaita'
# off: 'Numix [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3]'
gtk_shorthand="off"


# Enable/Disable gtk2 Theme / Icons / Font
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --gtk2
#
# Example:
# on:  'Numix [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3]'
# off: 'Adwaita [GTK3]'
gtk2="on"

# Enable/Disable gtk3 Theme / Icons / Font
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --gtk3
#
# Example:
# on:  'Numix [GTK2], Adwaita [GTK3]'
# off: 'Numix [GTK2]'
gtk3="on"


# IP Address


# Website to ping for the public IP
#
# Default: 'http://ident.me'
# Values:  'url'
# Flag:    --ip_host
public_ip_host="http://ident.me"

# Public IP timeout.
#
# Default: '2'
# Values:  'int'
# Flag:    --ip_timeout
public_ip_timeout=2


# Disk


# Which disks to display.
# The values can be any /dev/sdXX, mount point or directory.
# NOTE: By default we only show the disk info for '/'.
#
# Default: '/'
# Values:  '/', '/dev/sdXX', '/path/to/drive'.
# Flag:    --disk_show
#
# Example:
# disk_show=('/' '/dev/sdb1'):
#      'Disk (/): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#      'Disk (/mnt/Videos): 823G / 893G (93%)'
#
# disk_show=('/'):
#      'Disk (/): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#
disk_show=()

# Disk subtitle.
# What to append to the Disk subtitle.
#
# Default: 'mount'
# Values:  'mount', 'name', 'dir'
# Flag:    --disk_subtitle
#
# Example:
# name:   'Disk (/dev/sda1): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#         'Disk (/dev/sdb2): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#
# mount:  'Disk (/): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#         'Disk (/mnt/Local Disk): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#         'Disk (/mnt/Videos): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#
# dir:    'Disk (/): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#         'Disk (Local Disk): 74G / 118G (66%)'
#         'Disk (Videos): 74G / 118G (66%)'
disk_subtitle="mount"


# Song


# Manually specify a music player.
#
# Default: 'auto'
# Values:  'auto', 'player-name'
# Flag:    --music_player
#
# Available values for 'player-name':
#
# amarok
# audacious
# banshee
# bluemindo
# clementine
# cmus
# deadbeef
# deepin-music
# dragon
# elisa
# exaile
# gnome-music
# gmusicbrowser
# gogglesmm
# guayadeque
# iTunes
# juk
# lollypop
# mocp
# mopidy
# mpd
# netease-cloud-music
# pogo
# pragha
# qmmp
# quodlibet
# rhythmbox
# sayonara
# smplayer
# spotify
# strawberry
# tomahawk
# vlc
# xmms2d
# xnoise
# yarock
music_player="auto"

# Format to display song information.
#
# Default: '%artist% - %album% - %title%'
# Values:  '%artist%', '%album%', '%title%'
# Flag:    --song_format
#
# Example:
# default: 'Song: Jet - Get Born - Sgt Major'
song_format="%artist% - %album% - %title%"

# Print the Artist, Album and Title on separate lines
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --song_shorthand
#
# Example:
# on:  'Artist: The Fratellis'
#      'Album: Costello Music'
#      'Song: Chelsea Dagger'
#
# off: 'Song: The Fratellis - Costello Music - Chelsea Dagger'
song_shorthand="off"

# 'mpc' arguments (specify a host, password etc).
#
# Default:  ''
# Example: mpc_args=(-h HOST -P PASSWORD)
mpc_args=()


# Text Colors


# Text Colors
#
# Default:  'distro'
# Values:   'distro', 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num'
# Flag:     --colors
#
# Each number represents a different part of the text in
# this order: 'title', '@', 'underline', 'subtitle', 'colon', 'info'
#
# Example:
# colors=(distro)      - Text is colored based on Distro colors.
# colors=(4 6 1 8 8 6) - Text is colored in the order above.
colors=(distro)


# Text Options


# Toggle bold text
#
# Default:  'on'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --bold
bold="on"

# Enable/Disable Underline
#
# Default:  'on'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --underline
underline_enabled="on"

# Underline character
#
# Default:  '-'
# Values:   'string'
# Flag:     --underline_char
underline_char="-"


# Info Separator
# Replace the default separator with the specified string.
#
# Default:  ':'
# Flag:     --separator
#
# Example:
# separator="->":   'Shell-> bash'
# separator=" =":   'WM = dwm'
separator=" "
#separator=" " , arrow with equal sign (=>)


# Color Blocks


# Color block range
# The range of colors to print.
#
# Default:  '0', '15'
# Values:   'num'
# Flag:     --block_range
#
# Example:
#
# Display colors 0-7 in the blocks.  (8 colors)
# neofetch --block_range 0 7
#
# Display colors 0-15 in the blocks. (16 colors)
# neofetch --block_range 0 15
block_range=(0 15)

# Toggle color blocks
#
# Default:  'on'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --color_blocks
color_blocks="on" # USED TO BE: on

# Color block width in spaces
#
# Default:  '3'
# Values:   'num'
# Flag:     --block_width
block_width=3

# Color block height in lines
#
# Default:  '1'
# Values:   'num'
# Flag:     --block_height
block_height=1


# Progress Bars


# Bar characters
#
# Default:  '-', '='
# Values:   'string', 'string'
# Flag:     --bar_char
#
# Example:
# neofetch --bar_char 'elapsed' 'total'
# neofetch --bar_char '-' '='
bar_char_elapsed="-"
bar_char_total="="

# Toggle Bar border
#
# Default:  'on'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --bar_border
bar_border="on"

# Progress bar length in spaces
# Number of chars long to make the progress bars.
#
# Default:  '15'
# Values:   'num'
# Flag:     --bar_length
bar_length=15

# Progress bar colors
# When set to distro, uses your distro's logo colors.
#
# Default:  'distro', 'distro'
# Values:   'distro', 'num'
# Flag:     --bar_colors
#
# Example:
# neofetch --bar_colors 3 4
# neofetch --bar_colors distro 5
bar_color_elapsed="distro"
bar_color_total="distro"


# Info display
# Display a bar with the info.
#
# Default: 'off'
# Values:  'bar', 'infobar', 'barinfo', 'off'
# Flags:   --cpu_display
#          --memory_display
#          --battery_display
#          --disk_display
#
# Example:
# bar:     '[---=======]'
# infobar: 'info [---=======]'
# barinfo: '[---=======] info'
# off:     'info'
cpu_display="off"
memory_display="off"
battery_display="off"
disk_display="off"


# Backend Settings


# Image backend.
#
# Default:  'ascii'
# Values:   'ascii', 'caca', 'chafa', 'jp2a', 'iterm2', 'off',
#           'termpix', 'pixterm', 'tycat', 'w3m', 'kitty'
# Flag:     --backend
image_backend="kitty"

# Image Source
#
# Which image or ascii file to display.
#
# Default:  'auto'
# Values:   'auto', 'ascii', 'wallpaper', '/path/to/img', '/path/to/ascii', '/path/to/dir/'
#           'command output (neofetch --ascii "$(fortune | cowsay -W 30)")'
# Flag:     --source
#
# NOTE: 'auto' will pick the best image source for whatever image backend is used.
#       In ascii mode, distro ascii art will be used and in an image mode, your
#       wallpaper will be used.

#BASE CASE
# image_source="auto"

#MY CASE, my base
image_source="${HOME}/.config/neofetch/images/cat_bf.png"

# Ascii Options


# Ascii distro
# Which distro's ascii art to display.
#
# Default: 'auto'
# Values:  'auto', 'distro_name'
# Flag:    --ascii_distro
#
# NOTE: Arch and Ubuntu have 'old' logo variants.
#       Change this to 'arch_old' or 'ubuntu_old' to use the old logos.
# NOTE: Ubuntu has flavor variants.
#       Change this to 'Lubuntu', 'Xubuntu', 'Ubuntu-GNOME' or 'Ubuntu-Budgie' to use the flavors.
# NOTE: Arch, Crux and Gentoo have a smaller logo variant.
#       Change this to 'arch_small', 'crux_small' or 'gentoo_small' to use the small logos.
ascii_distro="auto"

# Ascii Colors
#
# Default:  'distro'
# Values:   'distro', 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num' 'num'
# Flag:     --ascii_colors
#
# Example:
# ascii_colors=(distro)      - Ascii is colored based on Distro colors.
# ascii_colors=(4 6 1 8 8 6) - Ascii is colored using these colors.
ascii_colors=(distro)

# Bold ascii logo
# Whether or not to bold the ascii logo.
#
# Default: 'on'
# Values:  'on', 'off'
# Flag:    --ascii_bold
ascii_bold="on"


# Image Options


# Image loop
# Setting this to on will make neofetch redraw the image constantly until
# Ctrl+C is pressed. This fixes display issues in some terminal emulators.
#
# Default:  'off'
# Values:   'on', 'off'
# Flag:     --loop
image_loop="off"

# Thumbnail directory
#
# Default: '~/.cache/thumbnails/neofetch'
# Values:  'dir'
thumbnail_dir="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-${HOME}/.cache}/thumbnails/neofetch"

# Crop mode
#
# Default:  'normal'
# Values:   'normal', 'fit', 'fill'
# Flag:     --crop_mode
#
# See this wiki page to learn about the fit and fill options.
# https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/What-is-Waifu-Crop%3F
crop_mode="normal"

# Crop offset
# Note: Only affects 'normal' crop mode.
#
# Default:  'center'
# Values:   'northwest', 'north', 'northeast', 'west', 'center'
#           'east', 'southwest', 'south', 'southeast'
# Flag:     --crop_offset
crop_offset="center"

# Image size
# The image is half the terminal width by default.
#
# Default: 'auto'
# Values:  'auto', '00px', '00%', 'none'
# Flags:   --image_size
#          --size
image_size="auto"

# Gap between image and text
#
# Default: '3'
# Values:  'num', '-num'
# Flag:    --gap
gap=3

# Image offsets
# Only works with the w3m backend.
#
# Default: '0'
# Values:  'px'
# Flags:   --xoffset
#          --yoffset
yoffset=0
xoffset=0

# Image background color
# Only works with the w3m backend.
#
# Default: ''
# Values:  'color', 'blue'
# Flag:    --bg_color
background_color=


# Misc Options

# Stdout mode
# Turn off all colors and disables image backend (ASCII/Image).
# Useful for piping into another command.
# Default: 'off'
# Values: 'on', 'off'
stdout="off"
```

Now my second question: Is it possible to remove the '(/)' after the harddisk icon?
The same pictures and config as above are used to set it so I refer to them.

Also bonus question: Why doesn't my title show up?

Comment: Alright well I feel stupid, the problem with the title was that I had not commented out "┌─────────=title=─────────┐".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the mount information in your `config.conf` with:

```
disk_subtitle="none"
```

For the battery, you will need to change the neofetch function `get_battery()`. You can either copy the entire neofetch shell script to somewhere else on your PATH and edit it, or put the revised version of only this function in your `config.conf` file. For the latter, copy all the lines:

```
get_battery() {
 ...
}
```

Then change in the function the line

```
                    prin "${subtitle:+${subtitle}${bat: -1}}" "$battery"
```

to

```
                    prin "${subtitle}" "$battery"
```

The `1` you see is because some systems have several batteries, and this distinguishes between them.

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonders!